# A proxy server in nodeJS to intercept http/https responses

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, https, proxy

I need to make a proxy server in nodeJS that modifies the response from a server. To access google.com, I shouldn't have to go to an address like http://localhost:8000/google to access it. The proxy should run in the background and I should be able to use google.com though https://google.com, if that makes sense. Could you please give me some basic code to work with?
I think this approach of mine is wrong:

```js
const http = require('http');
const httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

// Create the HTTP proxy server
const proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer();

// Create a local server to intercept requests
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('haha lol');
});
proxy.on('error', (err, req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(500, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('Something went wrong.');
});

server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('Proxy server started on port 8080');
});
```

I tried connecting to the server through `Internet Options` in the windows control panel, but I get an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement a SOCKS proxy, not a http proxy? Anyway, you'll have a hard time modifying the encrypted content from https://google.com so that your browser will still accept it; what are you appear to be trying to do is the definition of a man-in-the-middle attack.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what a proxy server would do, you configure your browser to use a background proxy server and access google with normal URL address.

I think more context info is need for your specific problem.

[Update]:
I think you should tell the server what to proxy, right?

Something like below webpack devserver configuration:

```
proxy: {
    '^/api': {
      target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/', // 后台服务地址
      changeOrigin: true,
      pathRewrite: {
        '^/api': '/api',
      },
      headers: {
        Connection: 'keep-alive'
      },
      // 
      onProxyReq: function (proxyReq, req, res, options) {
        console.info('Proxy API request ', req.url)
      }
    },
  }
```

Comment: i added more context